# Installing the BlueZ Utilities

Tags: utilities

I need to install the [bluez utilities](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/bluez.html). On [this site](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-unwired/0596005830/ch07s05.html#lnxunwired-CHP-7-TABLE-5) there are listed six utilities in a table, so I downloaded the latest bluez package `bluez-5.33.tar.xz` and extracted it. But how can I install these utilities now?

I also found the file `bluez-utils-3.36-i686-2_dvl.tgz` on:
http://www.develia.org/tarballs.php?p=networking

Do I need this file, or is it too old?

Comment: Which distribution are you using? You'll probably find an appropriate package there...

Comment: I am using `Linux version 2.6.32-44-generic - Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS `

Comment: Oh that's old... Try `sudo apt-get install bluez` anyway, that should work.

Comment: I can't use that command, it is a very special developer device where it is not possible. I can only install files. So is it only possible to install these utilities by installing the whole package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build and install `bluez` without using system packages, you need to extract the tarball somewhere and then use the standard three-step build dance:

```
tar xf bluez-5.33.tar.xz
cd bluez-5.33
./configure && make
sudo make install
```

You may need to add options to `./configure`, in particular `--prefix` if you want to install it somewhere other than the default `/usr/local`. `./configure --help` will list the available options. The `README` file lists the requirements for building the software.

Comment: Thank you, but how can i install the utilities only like instructed by the website in my first link?

Comment: *Linux Unwired* is rather outdated, at least as far as build instructions are concerned. You can either follow the instructions provided in the tarball you downloaded, or find a version of `bluez` contemporaneous with the book (2004). I strongly recommend the former!